# Training a convolutional neural network by layer-wise

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

Are there approaches to train a convolutional neural network by layer-wise(Instead of end-to-end), to understand how each layer contributes to the final architecture performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freeze every other layer and only train one layer at a time. After each epoch/iteration you can freez other layers and only train one other layer. So this is possible.

Comment: How is it possible to freeze layers in tensorflow?